# Facebook Fanpage Photo Upload

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using python sdk (https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk)

I am trying to upload images to fanpage timeline ,

```
    path = "/var/www/scheduler/media/userupload/3.jpg"
    page_id = "XXXXXXXX"
    access_token = "XXXXXX"
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
    resp = graph.put_photo(open(path),"This is awesome test",page_id)
```

i am getting an error "(#324) Missing or invalid image file" , Can any one help me ? Is it an api issue ?

How can i do this ?

[ I uploaded the source in my Test server (23.228.235.76/schedule/test.fb) with Debug mode ON ]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must specify an absolute path to a file, not a relative path.

Comment: "I think" is not an answer. You should have posted this as a comment. Or: write a little more complete post.

Comment: i am using an absolute path (path = "/var/www/scheduler/media/userupload/3.jpg" )

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, but i fixed this issue by using other lib.